# Criação de múltiplos arquivos zip

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com um problema no PHP/Laravel para criar vários arquivos zip de modo síncrono, eu copio todos comandos que são gerados e rodo no Shell, ele executa beleza, mas quando passo para o PHP executar só gera o primeiro arquivo.

Código do Controller.

```
foreach ($passwords as $p){
            if($i == 0){
                $command = 'zip -u -j -P '.$p.' '.$dir.'/'.$count.'.zip '.storage_path().'/app/'.$directory.'/'.$file1->getClientOriginalName();
                $commands->push($command);
            }else{
                $command = 'zip --quiet -j -P '.$p.' '.$dir.'/'.$count.'.zip '.storage_path().'/app/'.$directory.'/'.($count+1).'.zip';
                $commands->push($command);
            }
            $count--;
            $i++;
        }
        foreach ($commands as $p){
            echo $p.'<br/>';
        }
        foreach ($commands as $c){
            $process = new Process($c);
            $process->start();
            sleep(10);
            if($process->isTerminated()){
                sleep(1);
            }
            if ($errorOutput = $process->getErrorOutput()) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Process: ' . $errorOutput);
            }
        }
```

[Código que gerado no collect $commands.](https://pastebin.com/xwuEYb1X)

O Script só gera o arquivo 50.zip, não continua para frente.

Comment: Como você está instanciando variável `$commands`? Qual objeto ela instancia? Por que não utiliza-la como `array`, por exemplo `$commands[] = "comando";` ?

Comment: Ela é um collect do Laravel, como se fosse um array mesmo. Os dados são estão na memória, o problema é quando vai rodar no $process ai dá problema. Fala que o arquivo não foi encontrado, mas ele está lá.